# MTP file transfer: request to proceed, because "device can't play this" - how to fix permanent?

Tags: nexus-7, file-transfer, windows, media-files, mtp

I have Nexus 7 and often copy vide to see on it, but every time windows asks for proceed with reason "device can't play this file format".

Supported file formats is declared by media device, but when I copied video, I can play with standard player and with 3rd party.

How permanently fix this?

Comment: I think there is nothing to be fixed, just simply ignore the Windows alert and proceed copying your movies, then watch them on the device. What is the problem?!

Comment: Problem is minor: device provide incorrect info.

Comment: But I think it is not the device which provides incorrect info, but Windows thinks that a device connected through MTP, is capable of playing only 3GP and MP4 videos!

Comment: MTP standard says: device provide info… At developers site I foud only docs, how to provide info from my app.